# Visual Studio webbrowser c# not showing Jquery code

Tags: c#, windows

I am working with a Webbrowser element in visual Studio Community last version with c#.

I am loading the same page outside the app in Chrome, and inside the webbrowser seems that delete some elements. I can not access to a input file.. the HTML code inside the webbrowser change to something like this

```
  <DIV class="rcbScroll rcbWidth" style="WIDTH: 100%" 
      jQuery111108888789801282217="114">
```

with this weird numbers.. jQuery111108888789801282217 that in Chrome or any other browsers does not exists...

Anyone knows what is happening??

Comment: Try adding an HTTP header UserAgent to your request for Chrome : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent

Comment: I do not have access to the website.  My problem is when I try to load the web in Visual Studio in the webbrowser component.

Comment: When you connect to a website a HTTP Request is sent and the HTTP response is what you see in the browser.  The Request/Response have Headers, Body, and attachments. The headers in the Request are parameters that can give different Responses.  The UserAgent is an HTTP Header that can change the response.